# Executar função somente na primeira vez que abrir a página

Tags: javascript, html, apache-cordova, front-end

Estou desenvolvendo um app utilizando o **Phonegap**, o mesmo utiliza o front-end para criar apps, assim gostaria de fazer o seguinte:

- rodar uma função especifica (como por exemplo um alerta) na primeira vez que o aplicativo for aberto? E não ser mais mostrada ao menos que seja finalizado o app?

Comment: Não seria apenas colocar a função na inicialização do app?

Comment: utilizando o app initiliaze né?

Comment: Sim. imagino que ja resolveria o seu problema certo?

Comment: já sim, sou novo com o phonegap, agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize a função initialize, Veja um exemplo neste site:

http://pt.androids.help/q4068

Código:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
```

pode colocar o aviso dentro da função desta forma só ira executar quando o app for iniciado.